# Jolt transform array of documents. Move parent attributes to a child

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have an array of json objects that I need to transform using JOLT

**Input**

```json
[
  {
    "name": "john",
    "age": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "tom",
    "age": 12
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```json
[
  {
    "details": {
      "name": "john",
      "age": 12
    }
  },
  {
    "details": {
      "name": "tom",
      "age": 12
    }
  }
]
```

I currently have the following spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "details.&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which results in the entire array of objects being wrapped in "details" as well as each element of the array being assigned it index as its key.

```json
{
  "details" : {
    "0" : {
      "name" : "john",
      "Age" : 12
    },
    "1" : {
      "name" : "tom",
      "Age" : 12
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can revert the order as `"&.details"` in order to distinguish the objects by uncommon values(1,2,...) rather than the common literal `details` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&.details"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

then, get rid of the object labels within the last transformation spec

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]